# Not able to set actual device resolution in Emulator

Tags: android

I am developing an application which I need to test in Samsung I9000 whose resolution is 480*800. But when I try to  create a AVD Emulator with 480*800 resolution, I am getting a very big resolution. How to get the screen resolution of Emulator similar to Device.
I will be waiting for valuable reply.

Answer (score 2):

You can let the emulator scale itself to a real display size if you start the emulator manually. Using Eclipse you can achieve this by navigating to `Window->Android SDK and AVD Manager` then select a device and hit `Start...` in the popup which appears (Launch Options) you just check the `Scale display to real size` checkbox and set the screen size in inches and the monitor dpi. If you don't know your monitor dpi hit the question mark `?` and another popup will appear helping you to get the correct value. When all values are set just hit `Launch` and your are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Go to  Window > Android SDK and AVD Manager > New and in the Create New Android Virtual Device in the Skin section you should be able to do it.    Is that what you tried?    What exactly do you mean when you say you are getting a "very big resolution"?

Comment: I am not getting the resolution as of device's resolution. I am more height compared to real device.I select WVGA 800 while creating new AVD,and has checked the check box to Scale to REal size. I am getting Emulator some what bigger compared to Actual device screen